# Usage of cakePHP updateAll(): Possible to know where the $condition are met or not?

Tags: cakephp, update-all

I use cakephp updateAll() with $conditions to update database records
for example:

```
$this->stock->updateAll(
    array('stock.qty' => 'stock.qty+'.$difference),
    array('stock.qty' => $bufferedQty)
);
```

**My target:**
**"array('stock.qty' => $bufferedQty)"** is the condition have to be met for updating the database.
I use this condition to make sure the current process is holding the latest record for updating, that to prevent double update error.

**My problem**
Though I can prevent double update, updateAll() won't report if the **"array('stock.qty' => $bufferedQty)"** is met or not. I want to reply error if the condition is not met.

Is it possible know the condition met or not? Or any other better function I can choose?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want a count of the number of records that it updated?

Comment: yes. any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the code for the function in question, it appears that it returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: I see thanks. I found the getAffectedRow() could do so.